# NGINX fastcgi cannot get script name

Tags: nginx, cgi, fastcgi

I am setting up fastcgi on nginx.  I sort of have it working.  Inside my location block if i have `factcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/cgi-bin/hello.cgi;` it works.  However I don't want to hard code the link.

Setting fastcgi with the below configuration

```
factcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/cgi-bin/$fastcgi_script_name;
```

I get the following error

```
cannot get script name are document_root and script_name or (script_file) set and is the script executable? 
while reading response header upstream from upstream. client 127.0.0.1, 
server _, request "get /cgi-bin/hello.cgi"
```

On the webpage I get 403 Forbidden

`hello.cgi` is executable and works when I hard code it.
My [fastcgi_params](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nginx/nginx/master/conf/fastcgi_params)

Comment: Looks like your HTTP request is `/cgi-bin/hello.cgi`, so you should have `factcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www$fastcgi_script_name` instead of `factcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/cgi-bin/$fastcgi_script_name;`.

Comment: Usually it used like `root /var/www;` and then `factcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;`. When you want to change root directory of the site, the only thing you should change is `root` directive value.